# What does it mean to calculate "weight of SiO2 in the form of Si"?

Tags: elemental-analysis

This is with reference to the typical mass balance problems in iron making. Whenever we are asked to mole balance $\ce{SiO_2}$ it is treated this way:

$W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ from iron ore + $W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ from coke = **$W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ in the form of $W_{\ce{Si}}$** in hot metal+$W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ in slag.

Please explain the meaning of the highlighted part. What is the meaning of **"weight in the form of"**?

Comment: The sum expression looks weird. What kind of *work* $W$ silicon dioxide is supposed to perform?

Comment: @andselisk That is weight not work..LOL

Comment: Weight is denoted with a small letter $w$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_quantities)) and measured in Newtons which also makes no sense in this context. In reality, what you probably have here is *mass* $m$. Not many reasons to LOL, actually, as it's all pretty sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the silicon in $\ce{SiO2}$ is converted it of course ceases to be present as $\ce{SiO2}$, but you can "pretend" that it still is. It is algebraically simpler to compute a weight of $\ce{SiO2}$, equivalent to the reduced weight $W_{\ce{Si}}$. All you have to do is subtract the remaining weight of $\ce{SiO2}$ from the starting amount. This is a bit simpler then to report $W_{\ce{Si}}$, since the latter calculation requires conversions using molecular and atomic weights for $\ce{SiO2}$ and $\ce{Si}$, respectively.

It also makes it particularly easy to compute a quantity like %yield as follows:

$ \% yield = 100 \times W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ in the form of $W_{\ce{Si}}$ in hot metal/$(W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$from iron ore+ $W_{\ce{SiO_2}}$ from coke)

Here %yield refers to the molar yield of reduced Si relative to total starting amount of Si.